# DistributedCache Hadoop - FileNotFound

Tags: hadoop, filenotfoundexception, distributed-caching, distributed-cache

I'm trying to place a file in the distributed cache. In order to do this I invoke my driver class using the -files option, something like:

```
   hadoop jar job.jar my.driver.class -files MYFILE input output
```

The `getCacheFiles()` and the `getLocalCacheFiles()` return arrays of URIs/Paths containing MYFILE.
(E.g.: hdfs://localhost/tmp/hadoopuser/mapred/staging/knappy/.staging/job_201208262359_0005/files/histfile#histfile)

Unfortunately, when trying to retrieve MYFILE in the map task, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

I tried this in standalone(local) mode as well as in pseudo-distributed mode.

Do you know what might be the cause ?

**UPDATE:**

The following three lines:

```
System.out.println("cache files:"+ctx.getConfiguration().get("mapred.cache.files"));
uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(ctx.getConfiguration());
for(Path uri: uris){

      System.out.println(uri.toString());
      System.out.println(uri.getName());
      if(uri.getName().contains(Constants.PATH_TO_HISTFILE)){
       histfileName = uri.getName();
      }
}
```

print out this:

```
cache files:file:/home/knappy/histfile#histfile

/tmp/hadoop-knappy/mapred/local/archive/-7231_-1351_105/file/home/knappy/histfile

histfile
```

So, the file seems to be listed in the job.xml `mapred.cache.files` property and the local file seems to be present. Still, the FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check `mapred.cache.files` in your job's xml to see whether the file is in the cache.
The you can retrieve it in your mapper:

```
...
Path[] files = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
File myFile = new File(files[0].getName());
//read your file content
...
```

Comment: can you please take a look at the update ? It still doesn't find the file

Comment: how do you fetch your file from URIs/Paths?

Comment: yes, I solved the problem. I was trying to get it from the uri using the FS instance instantiated using that uri. I should've tried to get locally, which I did in the end and it works now. Thanks!